# No template named 'function'

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, g++

I'm trying to compile on mac a code written in C++ and there is a function

```
tuple<string, string, int> getURL(const string& url, const function<void(CURL*)>& opts)
{...}
```

with an error

```
      no template named 'function'
  ...int> getURL(const string& url, const funct...
                                          ^
```

I've tried to modify the functions header. After that I could compile that module, but the compiler couldn't link with the others:

```
"getURL(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::function<void (void*)> const&)", referenced from:
      CensysScanner::getHostInfo(Host*) in CensysScanner.cpp.o
      DebianLookup::FindVulnerability(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, OpSys, double) in DebianLookup.cpp.o
      DebianLookup::GetChangelog(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, OpSys, double) in DebianLookup.cpp.o
      EnterpriseLinuxLookup::FindVulnerability(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, OpSys, double) in EnterpriseLinuxLookup.cpp.o
      EnterpriseLinuxLookup::GetChangelog(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, OpSys, double) in EnterpriseLinuxLookup.cpp.o
      LooquerScanner::getHostInfo(Host*) in LooquerScanner.cpp.o
      ShodanScanner::getHostInfo(Host*) in ShodanScanner.cpp.o
      ...
```

I've also included functional module (`#include <functional>`) and I'm using std namespace (`using namespace std;`).

Comment: You probably can't get around making a [mcve] for this, though it will probably be hard. The good news is, when you did you will already know the answer.

Comment: Did you #include `<functional>`?

Comment: I've included <functional>.

Comment: @buduboti Which of the two errors are you asking about right now? The compilation error or the linker error? You said that you modified the code, in what way did you do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `std::function` works. I don't know why needed the `std::` because at the top of the file the namespace was told (`using namespace std;`), but it works.

Answer (score 3):

```
"getURL(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::function<void (void*)> const&)", referenced from:
```

This symbol the other object files reference has as parameter a `std::__1::function`. This is `std::function` from the standard library, which `function` in your first code block is apparently supposed to refer to.

Check that `#include<functional>` is included, that you are compiling with C++11 or later and write `std::function` instead of `function` or check that you have a `using` statement importing `function` from `std` into the current namespace, e.g. `using namespace std;` or `using std::function;`.

Comment: "*..., which appearently is supposed to be aliased to `function` in your first code block*" - most likely the OP simply has a `using namespace std` in their code

Comment: @RemyLebeau Bad choice of words, I meant "aliased" in the common sense, not aliased as in the language feature of a type alias. I will rewrite that.

Comment: I've edited my question: I'm using std namespace and I've included functional.

Comment: @buduboti Did you check the third step, compiling against C++11 or higher? If yes, then please try to provide more information, a [repro], preferably. Also check what compiler you are using exactly (gcc/g++ on macos is probably a symlink to clang/clang++) and if you are talking about still having the linker issue provide the relevant lines from the output of `nm` for both the object file generated from code containing your first block, as well as its output for (one of) the conflicting object files mentioned in the error. If you modified the first code block, show the modified version as well.

Comment: @uneven_mark The Makefile was generated my cmake, -std=c++14 was set as a flag, also now I tried to `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` 
The code isn't mine, it was written for windows, now I'm trying to compile to mac. I've solved some compiling issues, but I can't solve this. Tomorrow I'll text to the author and I hope that he can help to me.